# UITextfield text displayed as left aligned when the property is right in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, localization, uitextfield, text-alignment

I am working on an English / Arabic app that has localization. In one textfield I have set `textAlignment` property as `right`. But the content, numeric, displayed at right side. 
 I double checked it by debugging `textAlignment` property value and it indeed is `right`.

I have set alignment property programatically, as it will be changing as per language selection (i.e. on button tap). Then I set value in it and is being displayed as right aligned.

The thing is when I select the text field, suddenly the content moves to right side and displays as aligned right.

I change the layout to RTL and LTL programmatically with the following line:

```
UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 10):

Try this approach

```
 if isLangEn
    { 
        self.textF.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left  
        self.parentViewOfTextF.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttribute.forceLeftToRight  
    }
    else
    {   
        self.textF.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right
        self.parentViewOfTextF.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttribute.forceRightToLeft  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I sorted it out by myself. I ve been setting value first then setting alignment and layout during loading view. I changed the order in such a way that layout first and then set value. And it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

To set alignment of Label and Textfields text on changing language use the bellow line of code:

1. To check app language:

   ```
   class Language {

     static var isArabicLanguage : Bool {
       get {
              return currentAppleLanguage() == "ar"
        }
      }
   }
   ```
2. Create extension of UIViewController:

   ```
   extension UIViewController {

   //Align Textfield Text

   func loopThroughSubViewAndAlignTextfieldText(subviews: [UIView]) {
   if subviews.count > 0 {
       for subView in subviews {
           if subView is UITextField && subView.tag <= 0{
               let textField = subView as! UITextField
               textField.textAlignment = Language.isArabicLanguage ? .right: .left
           } else if subView is UITextView && subView.tag <= 0{
               let textView = subView as! UITextView
               textView.textAlignment = Language.isArabicLanguage ? .right: .left

           }

           loopThroughSubViewAndAlignTextfieldText(subviews: subView.subviews)
       }
     }
   }


   //Align Label Text
   func loopThroughSubViewAndAlignLabelText(subviews: [UIView]) {
   if subviews.count > 0 {
       for subView in subviews {
           if subView is UILabel && subView.tag <= 0 {
               let label = subView as! UILabel
               label.textAlignment = Language.isArabicLanguage ? .right : .left
           }
           loopThroughSubViewAndAlignLabelText(subviews: subView.subviews)
       }
      }
     }
   }
   ```
3. Create new class Localizer which inherit from UIViewController which help us to set allignment of each viewController.

   ```
   class LocalizerViewController: UIViewController {

      override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         self.loopThroughSubViewAndAlignTextfieldText(subviews: self.view.subviews)
         self.loopThroughSubViewAndAlignLabelText(subviews: self.view.subviews)
     }
   }
   ```
4. Now, Inherit all the ViewController to LocalizerViewController:

   ```
   class myViewController: LocalizerViewController {
          override func viewDidLoad() {
              super.viewDidLoad()
         }
   }
   ```

It will align all the label and textfields text to right or left according to your app language.

Comment: stop compare it with arabic because there is at least hebrew exists

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 14.1 (or less perhaps) there is a setting "Natural" in text alignment which solved problem for me.